# Why does String Array throw an error in JSP

Tags: arrays, string, jsp

Why does JSP fail to compile code with the following String array

```
         <%! String question[];
         question = new String[2];
         question[0] = "What is your name?";
         question[1] = "In what age group are you?";
         %>
```

But the code if the array is initialized as follows compiles JSP correctly. Why?

```
       <%!      
           String question[] = {"What is your name?","In what age group are you?"};     
        %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format for an array initialization is:

```
<%!      
  String question[] = new String[]{"What is your name?","In what age group are you?"};     
%>
```

Your first snippet doesn't compile because the initialization code is put directly into the generated class. E.g in Tomcat 9 the generated code starts with:

```
public final class test_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent,
                 org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceImports {

 String question[];
    question = new String[];
    question[0] = "What is your name?";
    question[1] = "In what age group are you?";

...
```

This causes a compile error since the statements are not allowed outside of a method body.

The code would work in a normal scriptlet, i.e. inside `<%` and `%>` since that code will be inserted into the render method.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am still confused because the same lines that fail in JSP work in a simple java class file and prints the output. So I am not able to understand why inline initialization works but not with array with size declaration style.

Answer (score 0):

The JSP declaration needs to only contain declaration w/ inline initialization. It cannot contain memory allocation steps. The memory allocation needed to be done in a scriptlet block instead. Once the code was updated as follows, JSP compiled and executed w/o any issues.

```
 <%!
     String q;
     String question [];
  %>

  <%

   question = new String[2];
   question[0] = "What is your name?";
   question[1] = "How old are you?";
   %>
```